# NiFi - Cannot convert CHOICE, type must be explicit

Tags: apache-nifi

Getting following error while inserting few thousands records to postgres DB.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZzJl.png)

Here is my `PutDatabaseRecord` config:

[PutDatabaseRecord config image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PIzy.png)

Comment: Can you share the relevant section of logs/nifi-app.log with the stack trace from that error? Also what does your target table look like, and can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send one record at a time using SplitProcessor instead of sending whole array of records. (Split Processor -> PutDatabaseRecord) For performance you can split and merge before inserting into database. (SplitProcessor -> Merge Processor -> PutDatabaseRecord processor)

Comment: Actually, using a record-based processor, as the OP is usind, is far more efficient than splitting and going row-by-row again. This problem has a straightforward solution (no workaround) here: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Cannot-convert-CHOICE-type-must-be-explicit/m-p/290187